# how to download the pdf through ajax call to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, pdf

It need page refresh to download the attachment response.so how i am suppose to be reload the page partially without reload the complete page using GET method ajax call.

The PDF download require page reload to show save as dialog.

In facebook they are doing the photo download without refresh the whole page.They reload the page partially.

any one help me?

Comment: What has page refresh to do with file download? Can you post relevant code so that we understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook is simply providing download link to image with force download headers. You can do it like this:

Do ajax request to get the url to your force download script, and redirect/open window popup to that link.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("/path/to/filename.pdf");
```